# 3 ways to say if:else, but which one?

Tags: javascript, logic

In an [interesting blog post](http://www.thomasfrank.se/3_ways_2_say_if.html), I read that there are three ways to write an `if:else` statement:

```
//method 1 - regular
if(boolean) {true condition} else {false condition}

//method 2 - shorthand
boolean ? (true condition) : (false condition)

//method 3 - logical operators
boolean && (true condition) || (false condition)
//eg: var c = r==0 && "small" || "big";
```

***EDIT:*** third method IS an `if:else` statement, when the first part of it becomes true, the whole statement turns to `true||(false condition)`. all modern compilers ignore the `false condition then`.

Now I have two questions here:

1. Which one of them is the most optimized? (from performance view, if any of them differs from the other, please explain why)
2. Is there any more methods to write an `if:else` statement?

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about the performance of these statements unless you are planning on running them a few thousand times per second.

If you are going to run them that often, test it yourself, you'll probably find different results under different browsers.

Comment: Yes! method 3 IS an `if:else` statement!

Comment: I know, I already edited that bit out. You'll hit some fun issues if you try c = r==0 && "" || "big"; though.

Comment: c will always equal "big" because false && "" || "big" will evaluate to "big". This will be a problem for any non truthy value you try and assign to c. e.g. false, 0, null.

Comment: No, `c` won't be always equal to "big", as `false, 0, null` values, `c` will become `null`! what is the problem?

Comment: Why the ??? is this answer getting negged? Do people believe optimising the if statement under all circumstances is a good idea? Assuming it does need optimising for whatever reason, testing is the only way to go. IE6 may be different to 7, 8 and 9 which may be different to the different versions of chrome, safari, firefox, etc. Only the OP knows which browser or subset of browers he cares about and testing the performance in them is easy...

Comment: Open a javascript console and put in var r = 0; then do var c = r==0 && "" || "big";.  Then check what c equals.

Comment: Yes, you're right, now I can see the fun part here, this happens because `""` evaluates to `false` in javascript.